# "Sensitive scopes you submitted for review aren't the same as the scopes that your app requests" React Native Google Fit

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-fit

I submitted my app for review that is using Android Google Fit API. I got the following response from Google.

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for applying for OAuth App verification your response reaching
> out.
>
> We noticed that the sensitive scopes you submitted for review aren't
> the same as the scopes that your app requests:
>
> **Scopes Submitted for Review​**
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write
>
> **Requested by your App**
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
>
> with the verification process, please update either of the following:
>
> The request for scopes in your app's codebase so that the scopes
> requested by your app match the scopes {in your Console/in review} or
> The scopes you submitted for review using the scope picker in your
> Console. If you're adding scopes to your Google Cloud project, make
> sure you provide a detailed Scope Justification for each additional
> scope you submit for review. You can find more information in the
> OAuth Application Verification FAQ. If you have other questions,
> please reply to this email to continue

Thing is in GCP I clearly only request read access:

[image: sensitive scopes img in GCP]

And then using React-Native-Google-Fit library in code I request:

```
 const options = {
     scopes: [Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ, Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ],
 };

 const authResponse = await GoogleFit.authorize(options);
```

Where does Google get the idea that I'm requesting write access? How do I fix this? I only need to read the exercises from Google Fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just had to add `fitness.location.read` to requested scopes. It seems Google was invalidly thinking I was requesting `fitness.activity.write` even though it should have been `fitness.location.read`.